# permission issue with symbolic link on apache http server

Tags: linux, apache, symlink, chmod

I have the following file permissions.

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       37 Aug 20 14:35 xxx -> /disk2/xxx

drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 4096 Aug 18 17:55 xxx

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   41 Aug 18 17:55 README
```

When accessing http://yy.yyy.yyy.yyy/xxx/README
I get the following error:
You don't have permission to access /xxx/README on this server.
why? I suspect symbolic link xxx is causing some issues, but not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Did you tell the server to allow following symlinks?

Comment: Beside what Ignacio said (Options FollowSymLinks) verify that Apache process has access (+x) on /disk2 and /disk2/xxx respectively.